# Off-center alignment of text inside a TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview, alignment

I have a layout/alignment problem with a TextView which I haven't yet been able to find a solution for, that is, I want to align text off-center inside a TextView horizontally.

To give a little more context, I have an ImageView and a TextView side by side, the ImageView touching the left edge of the screen and the TextView filling the rest of the screen horizontally, like this:

```
[-img-|-----text-----]
```

The TextView is configured as singleLine="true" and maxLines="1", so that it will be truncated if its too long for its horizontal space. My aim is to align the text in the center of the screen, not the center of the TextView, because there are other elements on the screen that are aligned to the center and I need the text aligment to match that.

So, if I use gravity="center" on the TextView, I get the image above, but what I actually want is

```
[-img-|--text--------]
```

I tried putting image and text in a RelativeLayout, so that the TextView actually touches both edges of the screen, which does what I want with respect to the alignment, except that if the text is long enough, the first characters will be hidden by the image, since the TextView lies behind the image view.

I also experimented with margins, padding and a compound drawable to the left, but the text is always centered relative to the available space (which I would consider the expected behavior).

Does anybody have any clues on how to achieve this alignment, i.e. relative to the center of a different component than the TextView, maybe programmatically at runtime? Thanks in advance for any helpful advice.

**Edit:** user Budius suggested using padding to the right to achieve a centered alignment which works but leads to long texts being truncated before the right edge of the TextView is reached and I'm looking for a solution that avoids that, i.e. that uses the entire avilable space, if possible.

Comment: You can achieve this with a FrameLayout, putting the textview as the first view with width = match_parent and gravity = center, and then the ImageView with layout_gravity left and wrap_content width. The problem is the length of the text, as it may be long enough to be under the image. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this approach appears to be equivalent of my attempt of putting the views inside a RelativeLayout - the possibility of the text being hidden behind the image is exactly one of the problems I would like to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that will center it and the move 20dp to the side.

`gravity:centre` `padding:right=20dp`

Comment: Thanks, you're right in that this gets me the alignment that I want, but as a consequence long texts are truncated even if there would be more space to the right (consumed by the padding), which looks a bit odd.

Comment: I understand the problem, but I can't think on any 'easy' way out. You could try programmatically check the text length and remove the padding as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
   android:layout_weight="1"
```

if it helps you..

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand how this helps, perhaps you could explain?

Comment: I have shared a code , which may not be a appropriate way (I know it). Otherwise FrameLayout is the best possible way which I know to solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the correct approach than too give it a try..

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it basically accomplishes the same thing as Budius' suggestion, but introduces the same problem, i.e. long texts don't fill the entire available space (taken up by the invisible image), but will be truncated before the right edge has been reached.